# DataTables pagination and search not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable, pagination

I have a DataTable that display data from a database. It uses the while loop to fetch data and display in the table. But the problem i'm having now is that, all the rows of data from the database appears in the table with no pagination. So lets say if i have 100 rows of data in the database, all appears in one long table and i would have to keep on scrolling down to view all data in the database. That means the records to be displayed per page and the pagination isn't working. The search and sorting aspect also doesn't work. Below is my codes and a screenshot of the datatable. Please help me because i'm stacked.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Event Date</th>
                                        <th>number</th>
                                        <th>Agent number</th>
                                        <th>Agent Name</th>
                                        <th>Remarks</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php

                                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM roaming");
                                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                ?>


                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td><?php echo $row['eventDate'];?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['number'];?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['agent_number'];?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo $row['service'];?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo $row['vpmn'];?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php   } //end of while loop ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

DataTable Screenshot[image]

Comment: I don't see your javascript where datatables is being initialized. Also, your code would output a new `<tbody>` for every result, which isn't necessarily desirable.

Comment: Thanks @Blake. Placing the `<tbody>` before the while loop in order not to output a new <tbody> for every result solves my problem.

Comment: You can probably just close this question, since it was just a formatting error and won't have much future value.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query "SELECT * FROM roaming" returns all rows, not just the first 10 of them, for example.

To get just the first ten rows, your SQL query should be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM roaming LIMIT 0,10"
```

To get rows from 10 to 20 (for next page) use a query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM roaming LIMIT 10,10"
```

Comment: Datatables is a javascript library. Your suggestion may be applicable if he set up server-side processing, which he hasn't mentioned at all.